# Update associated object within a FactoryBot trait

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, factory-bot

Sample Factory

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :fruit do
    name { "Kiwi" }
    status { "available" }
    store { Store.first }
  end

  trait :unaccessible do
    status { "unaccessible" }
    store { status: "closed", hours_before_open: 2 }
  end
end
```

Inside the trait block, I've been struggling to find a way to update the properties of the  associated Store object. Didn't find an example in the Traits section of the [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md). Also didn't find any example searching here in SO and Googling. Is this even possbile?

Comment: I suggest that you move the trait definition into the factory definition. Otherwise it will be a global trait that may clash with another trait with the same name. You'll save yourself from future headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `after` block to override those attributes.

Comment: Using an `after(:create)  do |fruit| ... end` callback made it work for me. Had to do `fruit.store.status = "closed"` and `fruit.store.hours_before_open = 2` inside the callback.

I still wonder why updating an associated object can't be done just within the trait block level itself though.

Comment: I wonder too, might be able to do something with the `instance` method, just wanted to give you an option I knew would work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be able to override the association within the trait as well, like this:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :fruit do
    name { "Kiwi" }
    status { "available" }
    store # assumes a factory :store
  end

  trait :unaccessible do
    status { "unaccessible" }
    association :store, status: "closed", hours_before_open: 2
  end
end
```

Then you don't need to do an additional DB write to update the store object in the after create.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Helen's answer! It's simple and avoids an extra write to the db. Also suggest to move the trait definition into the factory definition. Otherwise it's a global trait and it may clash with other global traits with the same name.

Just for fun, here's an alternative that uses [`transient`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/main/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes). That defines attributes that you can use to parameterize stuff inside the factory, and these attributes won't be set on the produced object.

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :fruit do
    transient do
      # Let this factory accept an extra attribute called "store_attrs"
      # which we'll use to parameterize the construction of "store".
      store_attrs { {} }
    end

    name { "Kiwi" }
    status { "available" }
    store { create(:store, **store_attrs) }

    trait :unaccessible do
      status { "unaccessible" }
      store_attrs { { status: "closed", hours_before_open: 2 } }
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can use `store_attrs` inside the specs to fine-tune the store without defining more traits:

```rb
let(:fruit) { FactoryBot.create(:fruit, store_attrs: { status: "renovating" }) }
# Note that `fruit.store_attrs` doesn't exist.
```

Though in this example you could just define the shop in a separate `let`:

```rb
let(:shop) { FactoryBot.create(:shop, status: "renovating") }
let(:fruit) { FactoryBot.create(:fruit, shop: shop) }
```